# Views not rendering domain-content

Tags: 7, views, users, domain-access, nodes

I have a strange thing going on here. I've a complex setup with [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) and [Smartqueue Domain](https://drupal.org/project/smartqueue_domain). I also have a view which filters the content to be shown depending on the Nodequeue status:

[image]

It does the job very well, but only for users with the "*Bypass Access Control*" permission (in this case only the super-admin). All other users, don't get the see anything but the title.
The title is rendered properly, only the images (and other CK Fields) are ignored. If you `dpm` the `$fields` in the view-template, you get `NULL` in your `$*fieldname*->content`...
The content itself, is perfectly visible for all users on the node-page.

Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this issue? Disabling/Enabling the SQL rewriting doesn't make any difference...